# Is there a way to automatically assign a User an ID in Firebase? IOS

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to Firebase and I have been working within IOS to identify the users by an automatically generated key. Essentially I'm creating a leaderboard with highscores and levels. Instead of having the user sign up for an account I want them to already have an ID so they can just start playing and write their high scores to the leader board. At the moment I have this code:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
ref?.child("Highscore").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(highscoreArray)
```

For some reason I'm getting an error that the "user" is non-existant. Is there a way to automatically generate one without having to force the user to choose a username etc. Also I've tried childByAutoID and i keep getting new IDs within the simulator everytime I run it.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minimally, you have to put the user through a sign-in process.  `Auth.auth().currentUser` won't return anything but null until that process is complete.  There is no workaround for this requirement.  The only way you get a uid is after the user signs in a creates an account.

If you don't want to user to have to do anything to sign in, you can enable and implement [anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth) to sign them in without requiring any input from them.  You can then upgrade their account later in order to [make it permanent](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/anonymous-auth#convert-an-anonymous-account-to-a-permanent-account), since anonymous accounts don't transfer between devices or survive an app uninstall.